# Question about a sentence in OWL Exercises

Tags: orthography

About the [Exercise: Adjective or Adverb Exercise 1:](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/exercises/2/2/8/) #3 *They proved to be perfectly exact measurements*...
Isn't this an impossible fact; consequently a incorrect sentence otherwise what is supposed to be according to OWL?

Comment: The question is presumably asking about the grammar of the sentence, not whether the situation described could actually happen in real life.

Comment: What the heck is OWL in this context?

Comment: @Marthaª I suspect he is referring to this: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are suggesting that the phrase "perfectly exact" represents a tautology, and that you can't have different grades of "exact" - something is exact or not. If this the case, there are two considerations to make here:

1. The sentence is an exercise in grammar, and has a grammatically correct solution (provided you choose the correct options from the ones offered).
2. Exact can mean ["capable of the greatest precision"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exact?s=t)  or ["very careful or accurate"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exact?show=0&t=1384491136). In this sense, there is an implied level of error, albeit very small, and therefore it is acceptable to describe the level of exactness, and that is, perfect, or without flaw.